# How to add minicart in cms block magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, cms-block

I tried adding this shortcode to my **cms block**

```
{{block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml"}}
```

but it doesn't show the **minicart dropdown** when clicked.